# CMake cannot find Boost on OS X with brew

Tags: macos, boost, cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to use CMake to compile another library and it requires Boost.

I have installed both CMake and Boost using [brew](http://brew.sh) on OS X 10.10 Yosemite, but CMake refuses to find it. Boost is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2`

I've tried the following:

- Setting `-DBoost_DIR` and `-DBOOST_ROOT` with the above path
- Setting `-DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR` and `-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR` with the above path + `/include`
- Setting any and all of these options in the CMakeLists.txt file
- Compiling Boost myself, and pointing the above vars to my own build
- Trying out similar solutions to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617891/cmake-cannot-find-boost-any-longer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280823/cmake-not-finding-boost), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303430/cmake-cannot-find-boost-libraries). The only answer that I found that mentioned brew on OS X was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685809/get-cmake-and-home-brew-to-work-together), and the same solution did not work for me.

Why is CMake blatantly ignoring my instructions? :(

**Edit:** [CMake output from -DBoost_DEBUG=ON](http://pastebin.com/ndedDmL8)

Comment: Can you rerun cmake with `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` and post the output?

Comment: @Fraser Done, link in the question

Comment: Can you also give the full path (including filename) to your Boost.System library please?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Had this issue when I installed boost using `brew install boost`. Instead use `brew install boost-python`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a separate homebrew package of `boost-python3`. With it installed, CMake does find Boost:

```
brew install boost-python3
```

gives me

```
> mkdir build ; ( cd build ; cmake .. )
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 6.0.0.6000056
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 6.0.0.6000056
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python (found version "2.7.9")
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.5")
-- Boost version: 1.56.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

(I have problems linking, but that's another story)

Comment: It failed to located boost which followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653001/unable-to-link-against-boost-python-on-os-x (For boost:python and python3)

Comment: Running `brew install boost-python` resulted in the error "Error: boost-python has been disabled because it does not build!". But `brew install boost` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was also having trouble compiling something with C++/Python/Boost/CMake (Specifically, I was trying to build https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM).

I was getting an error like this

```
Linking CXX shared library .../OpenSfM/opensfm/csfm.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::python::instance_holder::deallocate(_object*, void*)", referenced from:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::python::instance_holder::deallocate(_object*, void*)", referenced from:
...
```

Inspired by the above comment, I tried to find this mythical "boost-python", but it didn't exist. Instead, I wound up using homebrew to reinstall normal boost with python.

```
brew install boost --with-python
```

That worked. CMake could now find boost and whatever python boost things it needed, and the compilation succeeded.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: `Warning: boost@1.59: this formula has no --with-python option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: `brew install boost --with-python `

seems to have been a temporary solution, we're back to

`brew install boost-python`

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrading both cmake and boost to their newest version solved the problem

```
brew upgrade boost cmake
```